# Understanding higher order functions in JS: how does the following code guarantee that the code will only be called once?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I am trying to understand functional programming and saw the following example:

```
function onceOnly(f) {
    var hasRun = false;
    return function() {
        if(!hasRun){
            hasRun = true;
            return f();
        }
    }
}

// Call as many times as you like
var sendWelcomeEmail = onlyOnce(function() {
    emailServer.send(...);
});
```

There are a few things that I do not understand about this.

- This technique should guarantee that `emailServer.send(...)` will be called only once. How does it do so? How does the state of `hasRun` get saved?
- Is there any use to creating a function which returns `f()` inside `onceOnly(f)`? Why did we not simply do the following:

```
function onceOnly(f) {
    var hasRun = false;
    if(!hasRun){
        hasRun = true;
        return f();
    }
}
```

The source of this code can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqO4TcNLjl0)

Thank you.

Comment: You can see this answer for information about how the state of `hasRun` is "saved": [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aim of `onlyOnce` is to *return* a function, not *calling* a function. Your second example is calling the function and return the result of `f`.

Wherease, with the first implementation

```
//return a reference to an anonymous function
var sendWelcomeEmail = onlyOnce(...);
//you can use it to call after
sendWelcomeEmail();
```

Simply put a `console.log()` just before `return f()` you'll see the difference.

`hasRun` is first initiate with `false`. Once `sendWelcomeEmail()` is called, `hasRun` will be set to `true`. Since `sendWelcomeEmail` is referenced to an anonymous function, it is unique and exist in the memory, a second call to this same function will not trigger `f()` because `hasRun` is also uniquely referenced and got memorized.

Comment: I see, so it is because `sendWelcomeEmail` holds a reference to `hasRun` in the memory, if I understood this correctly? Which would mean that `hasRun` will get saved once it is changed.

Comment: Yes, as long as the anonymous function still exist. `hasRun` is still used and get referenced in memory